# Use regex to check the attribute in Javascript variables

Tags: regex

The JS code shows below, I want to use regex to match the "logging" value in all "myfunc.call" method. I use `(myfunc|\w+)\.call(.|\n)*logging`, then it won't find all 5 functions,  how to write this regex?

```
myfunc.call({
                                      "logging" : true
                                    });

myfunc.call({
    "logging" : true,
    //"mode": true,
  }, "project1");
myfunc.call({
    "devMode": true,
    "logging" : false,
  }, "project1");

myfunc.call({
    "apiKey":  "xxx",
    "baseURL": "HTTP://xxx",  // url used when not in dev mode
    "mode": false,   // mode
    "logging": true,  // logs events
  }, "project1");

myfunc.call({
    "apiKey":  "xxx"
  }, "project1");
```

In this case, I want to check which function has the value that the logging attribute is true, only 3 function match it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the example data, you could start matching `myfunc\.call` or `\w+\.call` if the function name can differ and match all following lines that do not start with the function or logging.

The value of `"logging"` can be captured in a group `(true|false)` matching either true or false, or a non whitespace char except a comma `([^\s,]+)` if there can be other values without whitespaces.

```
^myfunc\.call\({(?:\r?\n(?!\s*(?:"logging"|myfunc\.call)).*)*\r?\n.*"logging"\s*:\s*(true|false)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `myfunc\.call\({` Match `myfunc.call({`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\r?\n` Match a newline
  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

    - `\s*(?:"logging"|myfunc\.call)` Match either `"logging" or`myfunc.call`
  - `)` Close lookahead
  - `.*` Match the whole line
- `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `\r?\n.*"logging"` Match a newline, then match until "logging"
- `\s*:\s*` Match `:` between whitespace chars
- `(true|false)` Capture the value in **group 1**

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gUFD7z/1)